# CSP refusing form submission even when 'self' source matches

Tags: google-chrome, content-security-policy

I have a form like this:

```
<form action="/login.php" method="post" id="loginform" autocomplete="on" novalidate="novalidate">
```

The page it is served from has a CSP header that includes:

```
form-action 'self'
```

But in Chrome Canary dev tools, I see this sequence when I load the page and then submit it:

> Navigated to https://www.example.com/login.php
>
> Refused to send form data to 'https://www.example.com/login.php' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "form-action 'self'".

The page I navigated to clearly matches the form action (which is a relative URL), so the target is indeed `'self'`. So why is this failing the CSP check?

Oddly, if I submit the form a second time, it works correctly. Neither Safari nor Firefox complain about this.

Is this a Canary bug, or something else wrong?

Comment: I checked with regular Chrome, and it acts the same way.

Comment: Maybe your `login.php` performs a redirect from `example.com` to `www.example.com` while operation? Or maybe you do use non-standard port number?

Comment: Nope, the error is on the first hit, and it’s on the same port throughout

Comment: How you can be sure about "first hit" if Chrome checks [all chain and block redirects](https://github.com/w3c/webappsec-csp/issues/8#issuecomment-406463864)?

Comment: That thread is awful! By the time it rejects the form submission, it’s already too late, as it’s already happened. It’s not blocking form submission at all, only subsequent redirects, which seems like a terrible idea. The only reliable way out of that I can see is to lower security, as others in that thread mention! It also explains why the second request works – it’s because the browser is lying about what it did.

Comment: It's not "too late", because request was done to the host allowed via `'self'` it's secure. I think that host was changed from non-www to a www-version after redirect, it's a reason for lock in Chrome. `'self'` token covers only hostname from address bar (host from which the page was loaded). Alternatively you can use `form-action example.com www.example.com` or `form-action example.com *.example.com` instead of `'self'`.

Comment: You were quite right here – there was a www to domain redirect *after* the form submission. I'd still classify this as a bug though – Chrome allows the submission to happen (because it's permitted by the form-action rule), but then misreports the subsequent redirect as a form-action contravention, even though the form submission was successful. That's just plain unhelpful. if it has a problem with a redirect, it should report it as a problem with the redirect, not the request that happened beforehand.